# Error de autorizacion en node/express con JWT

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, jsonwebtoken

estoy realizando el backend de una webapp con node/express y jsonwentoken para las autorizaciones, tengo un problema de tipo JsonWebTokenError: jwt must be provided en mi proyecto al momento de hacer una solicitud a mi servidor local, al middleware le llega el jwt como undefined a pesar de que se lo envío en la solicitud:

Este es la funcion qe verifica el token:

```
export const authGuard = (req, _res, next) => {
    const authorization = req.headers.authorization;

    if (!authorization)
        throw new UnAuthorizedError("No se encuentra autenticado");

    try {
        const token = authorization.split(" ")[1];
        console.log("ESTE ES EL TOKEN QUE VIENE DEL REQUEST::", token);
        const payload = verify(token, process.env.JWT_ACCESS_SECRET);
        req.jwt_payload = payload;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        throw new UnAuthorizedError("Fallo la verificación del token");
    }

    return next();
};
```

Este es el endpoint donde se utiliza esta verificacion:

```
router.get("/list", authGuard, async (_req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const todos = await getAllUsers();
        res.json(todos);
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
});
```

Y esta es la petición que hago por insomnia:

```
localhost:8080/user/list

HEADERS : authorization: token
```

Este es el error que me sale en consola:

```
ESTE ES EL TOKEN QUE VIENE DEL REQUEST:: undefined 
JsonWebTokenError: jwt must be provided
```

Comment: Qué token le estás pasando?... muy probablemente debe ser que estás pasando una cadena como "myToken" que NO tiene espacios, por lo cual al hacer el .split(" ")[1] te retorna undefined

Comment: Efectivamente el error se encontraba en esa parte, eliminando el Split si funciona, no es necesario.

Answer (score 0):

Veo que el error radica en el split, publico la respuesta para que se guíen.

En este caso se está pasando una cadena SIN espacios, por ejemplo '123' y al hacer un `split(" ")` retorna `["123"]` por lo que al acceder a la posición `[1]` retorna undefined dado que no existe.

Esto de hacer un `split` a el token es común principalmente cuando el token viene acompañado de la palabra "Bearer", por ejemplo "Bearer myToken", en este caso SI se debería de hacer el `split(" ")[1]`

He visto esa práctica en muchos tutoriales de JsonWebToken y hasta en la misma documantación de los mismos, ya es decisión de cada quién si lo utiliza así o directamente con el token sin ninguna otra palabra.